# Complex web app multithreaded testing (not load)

Tags: mysql, testing, transactions, web, functional-testing

I have one complex web application which intensive interact with the database. I lock db (MySQL InnoDB) within some request`s subset to prevent data integrity violation (use 'begin' ... 'commit' command sequence). Before request amount is less than N app works good. But when request amount will be greater than N locking errors has appears ('Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'). 
I have a lot of functional test. All functional tests use 'single-client schema' emulation to test various scenarious of app using. They all is passed well. But how can I test my app with multiple clients connections (I want to able verify DB state at any time while test is run)? It means this is not simple load testing AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JMeter for that using :

- Http sampler at start
- once you identify the queries involved, you could use db sampler if you want to reproduce more simply or rapidly to test resolution

Regards